# Celery : Task not execute from queue after the first few times

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

**[Prerequisite]**

- Django==1.5.8
- celery==3.0.23
- django-celery==3.0.23
- amqp==1.4.6

**[Steps]**

- django *views.py* send message via *RabbitMQ* to *celery task queue*
- *Celery* read messages from queue and execute tasks in order
- Each task wouldn't take long time

**[Problem]**

- For the first few times, celery successfully executed tasks but number of tasks is not reduced from the queue (Task is constantly stacked up at the queue)
- Finally, celery is not executing task from queue after the first few times

**[Hint]**

- I thought that following could be hints to solve problem
- For the first few times, task is executed well but it is not removed from the queue
- `Task utils.tasks.do_things_1[027918df-a6ef-4712-a8c8-5b380d5bd0f6] succeeded in 1415464878.25s: None` => Why does it take so long?

**[Detail description with log]**

- *Check number of tasks and worker*

> $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages consumers | grep celery
>
> > **celery 0   0**       (0 tasks, 0 worker)

- *Celery Information when starts with Debug mode*

> $ ./manage.py celery worker --loglevel=debug
>
> > celery@75e28d96-1a33-4e08-8283-a31813a4124d v3.0.23 (Chiastic Slide)
> >
> > Linux-3.2.0-34-generic-pae-i686-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
> >
> > [config]
> >
> > > broker:      amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
> > >
> > > app:         default:0xb6b2188c (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
> > >
> > > concurrency: 1 (processes)
> > >
> > > events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
> >
> > [queues]
> >
> > > celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
> >
> > [Tasks]
> >
> > > utils.tasks.**do_things_1**
> > >
> > > utils.tasks.**do_things_2**
> > >
> > > utils.tasks.**do_things_3**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,769: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] Loading modules.
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,771: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] Claiming components.
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,771: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] Building boot step graph.
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,772: DEBUG/MainProcess] [Worker] New boot order: {ev, queues, beat, pool, 
> >     mediator, autoreloader, timers, state-db, autoscaler, consumer}
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,774: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.worker.hub.Hub...
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,774: DEBUG/MainProcess] celery.worker.hub.Hub OK!
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,774: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.concurrency.processes.TaskPool...
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,782: DEBUG/MainProcess] celery.concurrency.processes.TaskPool OK!
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,787: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.worker.mediator.Mediator...
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,788: DEBUG/MainProcess] celery.worker.mediator.Mediator OK!
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,788: DEBUG/MainProcess] Starting celery.worker.consumer.Consumer...
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,789: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@75e28d96-1a33-4e08-8283-a31813a4124d ready.
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,789: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Re-establishing connection to the broker...
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,800: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'copyright': u'Copyright (C) 2007-2013 GoPivotal, Inc.', u'capabilities': {u'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, u'connection.blocked': True, u'authentication_failure_close': True, u'basic.nack': True, u'consumer_priorities': True, u'consumer_cancel_notify': True, u'publisher_confirms': True}, u'platform': u'Erlang/OTP', u'version': u'3.2.4'}, mechanisms: [u'PLAIN', u'AMQPLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,801: DEBUG/MainProcess] Open OK!
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,801: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//.
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,802: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 1
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,803: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,804: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: basic.qos: prefetch_count->4
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,805: DEBUG/MainProcess] using channel_id: 2
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,805: DEBUG/MainProcess] Channel open
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:09:13,812: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Ready to accept tasks!

- *Check number of tasks and worker*

> $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages consumers | grep celery
>
> > **celery 0   1**       (0 tasks, 1 worker)

- *Some event occured in views.py and send message to execute **do_things_1, do_things_2, do_things_3**(1st attempts)*

> > [2014-11-16 14:53:51,874: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: utils.tasks.**do_things_1**[027918df-a6ef-4712-a8c8-5b380d5bd0f6] eta:[2014-11-16 14:53:52.835084+09:00]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:51,875: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: utils.tasks.**do_things_2**[a1c09645-32fb-4399-802b-60ca826fa6bc] eta:[2014-11-16 14:53:52.851516+09:00]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:51,880: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: utils.tasks.**do_things_3**[5a66f885-baf2-49ab-b82f-733d2b68fe7b] eta:[2014-11-16 14:53:52.852527+09:00]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:51,880: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: basic.qos: **prefetch_count->7**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:52,882: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: basic.qos: **prefetch_count->4**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:52,917: DEBUG/MainProcess] Mediator: Running callback for task: utils.tasks.**do_things_1**[027918df-a6ef-4712-a8c8-5b380d5bd0f6]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:52,918: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply  (args:('utils.tasks.**do_things_1**', '027918df-a6ef-4712-a8c8-5b380d5bd0f6', [u'0301010101', u'1'], {}, {'utc': True, 'is_eager': False, 'chord': None, 'group': None, 'args': [u'0301010101', u'1'], 'retries': 0, 'delivery_info': {'priority': None, 'routing_key': u'celery', 'exchange': u'celery'}, 'expires': None, 'task': 'utils.tasks.do_things_1', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'hostname': '************************', 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': '2014-11-16T05:53:52.835084', 'id': '027918df-a6ef-4712-a8c8-5b380d5bd0f6'}) kwargs:{})
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:52,918: DEBUG/MainProcess] Mediator: Running callback for task: utils.tasks.**do_things_2**[a1c09645-32fb-4399-802b-60ca826fa6bc]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:52,918: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply  (args:('utils.tasks.**do_things_2**', 'a1c09645-32fb-4399-802b-60ca826fa6bc', [u'0301010101', u'1'], {}, {'utc': True, 'is_eager': False, 'chord': None, 'group': None, 'args': [u'0301010101', u'1'], 'retries': 0, 'delivery_info': {'priority': None, 'routing_key': u'celery', 'exchange': u'celery'}, 'expires': None, 'task': 'utils.tasks.do_things_2', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'hostname': '*********************', 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': '2014-11-16T05:53:52.851516', 'id': 'a1c09645-32fb-4399-802b-60ca826fa6bc'}) kwargs:{})
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:52,918: DEBUG/MainProcess] Mediator: Running callback for task: utils.tasks.**do_things_3**[5a66f885-baf2-49ab-b82f-733d2b68fe7b]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 14:53:52,918: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply  (args:('utils.tasks.**do_things_3**', '5a66f885-baf2-49ab-b82f-733d2b68fe7b', [u'0301010101', u'1', u'1'], {}, {'utc': True, 'is_eager': False, 'chord': None, 'group': None, 'args': [u'0301010101', u'1', u'1'], 'retries': 0, 'delivery_info': {'priority': None, 'routing_key': u'celery', 'exchange': u'celery'}, 'expires': None, 'task': 'utils.tasks.do_things_3', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'hostname': '*************************', 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': '2014-11-16T05:53:52.852527', 'id': '5a66f885-baf2-49ab-b82f-733d2b68fe7b'}) kwargs:{})

- **I've checked that do_things_1, do_thins_2, do_things_3 executed well from the browser**
- *Check number of tasks and worker* **(As you can see, task is not reduced from the queue)**

> $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages consumers | grep celery
>
> > **celery 3   1**       (3 tasks, 1 worker)

- ***Repeat** to execute **do_things_1, do_things_2, do_things_3**(2nd attempts)*

> > [2014-11-16 15:27:54,060: DEBUG/MainProcess] **Task accepted: utils.tasks.do_things_1**[027918df-a6ef-4712-a8c8-5b380d5bd0f6] pid:23793
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:54,060: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: utils.tasks.**do_things_1**[2ea06e92-c617-460e-9275-98d4c4f79394] eta:[2014-11-16 15:27:55.048622+09:00]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:54,060: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: basic.qos: **prefetch_count->5**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:54,063: INFO/MainProcess] **Task utils.tasks.do_things_1[027918df-a6ef-4712-a8c8-5b380d5bd0f6] succeeded in 1415464878.25s: None**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:54,063: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: utils.tasks.**do_things_2**[cad7b687-7ef6-4f99-a06e-4a038369837d] eta:[2014-11-16 15:27:55.061913+09:00]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:54,063: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: basic.qos: **prefetch_count->6**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:54,065: DEBUG/MainProcess] **Task accepted: utils.tasks.do_things_2[a1c09645-32fb-4399-802b-60ca826fa6bc] pid:23793**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:54,066: INFO/MainProcess] Got task from broker: utils.tasks.**do_things_3**[ceee2b27-5cc0-45cc-9a00-e15a361fa92f] eta:[2014-11-16 15:27:55.064312+09:00]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:54,066: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: basic.qos: **prefetch_count->7**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:55,068: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: basic.qos: **prefetch_count->4**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:55,101: DEBUG/MainProcess] Mediator: Running callback for task: utils.tasks.**do_things_1**[2ea06e92-c617-460e-9275-98d4c4f79394]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:55,101: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply  (args:('utils.tasks.**do_things_1**', '2ea06e92-c617-460e-9275-98d4c4f79394', [u'0301010101', u'1'], {}, {'utc': True, 'is_eager': False, 'chord': None, 'group': None, 'args': [u'0301010101', u'1'], 'retries': 0, 'delivery_info': {'priority': None, 'routing_key': u'celery', 'exchange': u'celery'}, 'expires': None, 'task': 'utils.tasks.do_things_1', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'hostname': '******************************', 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': '2014-11-16T06:27:55.048622', 'id': '2ea06e92-c617-460e-9275-98d4c4f79394'}) kwargs:{})
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:55,105: DEBUG/MainProcess] Mediator: Running callback for task: utils.tasks.**do_things_2**[cad7b687-7ef6-4f99-a06e-4a038369837d]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:55,105: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply  (args:('utils.tasks.**do_things_2**', 'cad7b687-7ef6-4f99-a06e-4a038369837d', [u'0301010101', u'1'], {}, {'utc': True, 'is_eager': False, 'chord': None, 'group': None, 'args': [u'0301010101', u'1'], 'retries': 0, 'delivery_info': {'priority': None, 'routing_key': u'celery', 'exchange': u'celery'}, 'expires': None, 'task': 'utils.tasks.do_things_2', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'hostname': '*************************', 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': '2014-11-16T06:27:55.061913', 'id': 'cad7b687-7ef6-4f99-a06e-4a038369837d'}) kwargs:{})
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:55,105: DEBUG/MainProcess] Mediator: Running callback for task: utils.tasks.**do_things_3**[ceee2b27-5cc0-45cc-9a00-e15a361fa92f]
> >
> > [2014-11-16 15:27:55,106: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply  (args:('utils.tasks.**do_things_3**', 'ceee2b27-5cc0-45cc-9a00-e15a361fa92f', [u'0301010101', u'1', u'1'], {}, {'utc': True, 'is_eager': False, 'chord': None, 'group': None, 'args': [u'0301010101', u'1', u'1'], 'retries': 0, 'delivery_info': {'priority': None, 'routing_key': u'celery', 'exchange': u'celery'}, 'expires': None, 'task': 'utils.tasks.do_things_3', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'hostname': '*******************************', 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': '2014-11-16T06:27:55.064312', 'id': 'ceee2b27-5cc0-45cc-9a00-e15a361fa92f'}) kwargs:{})

- **I've checked that do_things_1, do_thins_2, do_things_3 executed well from the browser**
- *Check number of tasks and worker* **(As you can see, task is reduced partially)**

> $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages consumers | grep celery
>
> > **celery 4   1**       (4 tasks, 1 worker)

- ***Repeat** to execute **do_things_1, do_things_2, do_things_3** (3rd attempts)*
- **Celery didn't log anything and do_things_1, do_thins_2, do_things_3 not executed!**
- *Check number of tasks and worker* **(As you can see, task is increased)**

> $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages consumers | grep celery
>
> > **celery 7   1**       (7 tasks, 1 worker)

- When I **terminate it by "Ctrl+C"**, it logs like following

> celeryd: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
>
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:52,922: DEBUG/MainProcess] Stopping celery.worker.consumer.Consumer...
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:52,923: DEBUG/MainProcess] consumer: Stopping consumers...
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:52,923: DEBUG/MainProcess] Stopping celery.worker.mediator.Mediator...
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,638: DEBUG/MainProcess] Stopping celery.concurrency.processes.TaskPool...
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,638: INFO/MainProcess] Task utils.tasks.**do_things_2**[a1c09645-32fb-4399-802b-60ca826fa6bc] succeeded in 1415467757.76s: None
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,639: DEBUG/MainProcess] **Task accepted: utils.tasks.do_things_3[5a66f885-baf2-49ab-b82f-733d2b68fe7b] pid:23793**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,639: INFO/MainProcess] **Task utils.tasks.do_things_3[5a66f885-baf2-49ab-b82f-733d2b68fe7b] succeeded in 1415467757.75s: None**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,640: DEBUG/MainProcess] **Task accepted: utils.tasks.do_things_1[2ea06e92-c617-460e-9275-98d4c4f79394] pid:23793**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,640: INFO/MainProcess] **Task utils.tasks.do_things_1[2ea06e92-c617-460e-9275-98d4c4f79394] succeeded in 1415465715.65s: None**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,640: DEBUG/MainProcess] **Task accepted: utils.tasks.do_things_2[cad7b687-7ef6-4f99-a06e-4a038369837d] pid:23793**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,641: INFO/MainProcess] **Task utils.tasks.do_things_2[cad7b687-7ef6-4f99-a06e-4a038369837d] succeeded in 1415465715.64s: None**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,641: DEBUG/MainProcess] **Task accepted: utils.tasks.do_things_3[ceee2b27-5cc0-45cc-9a00-e15a361fa92f] pid:23793**
> >
> > [2014-11-16 16:15:53,642: INFO/MainProcess] Task utils.tasks.update_apartboard_1st_load_page_cache[ceee2b27-5cc0-45cc-9a00-e15a361fa92f] succeeded in 1415465715.63s: None

- **do_things_1, do_things_2, do_things_3 not executed** (Check from the browser)
- *Check number of tasks and worker* **(As you can see, task is reduced from the queue)**

> $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages consumers | grep celery
>
> > **celery 3   0**       (3 tasks, 0 worker)

- Purge task queue

> $ ./manage.py celeryctl purge
>
> $ sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues name messages consumers | grep celery
>
> > **celery 0   0**       (0 tasks, 0 worker)

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrade Celery version** from `3.0.23` to `3.0.25` solved this problem.

However, I still don't know the cause of the failure.